# « Avoir rapport à », « avoir un rapport avec » ou « concerner »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Contexte.

Renaud - Salut Rémi j’ai besoin de te voir s’il te plaît.

Rémi - Il est actuellement 21h, il se fait tard, est-ce qu’on pourrait remettre ça à demain? Je suis certain que ça peut attendre, ce n’est pas la première fois que tu me fais ce coup-là.

Renaud - Non j’ai vraiment besoin de te voir, je ne suis pas près de dormir.

Rémi - Je me rendrais volontiers chez toi si j’avais des fonds pour faire le plein d’essence, malheureusement je reçois ma paie seulement demain.

Renaud - Je peux te faire un virement Interac immédiatement.

Rémi - D’accord, j’imagine que ça ne doit pas **avoir rapport à/ avoir un rapport avec/ concerner** ta situation financière, sinon tu ne m’aurais pas proposé de déposer une somme dans mon compte.

Je suis ouvert à des reformulations.

Comment: *Déposer une somme dans* est maladroit dans le contexte. Les dépôts concernent le fait d'apporter physiquement de l'argent à la banque. On ne l'emploie pas s'agissant d'un virement. De plus on dépose *sur* un compte et non *dans* celui-ci.

Comment: @ArwynFr Je vous remercie de l’explication en tête du commentaire. En revanche, je pense qu’on peut dire aussi « déposer dans un compte », du moins cette tournure est courante au Québec.

Comment: https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_d&page=9n6ZkW09g-Tc.html

Comment: Je ne connais pas l'usage au Québec, en tout cas cette formulation choquera un européen comme moi :)

Comment: Ici, l'usage aurait plutôt voulu qu'on dise : *sinon tu n’aurais pas proposé de créditer mon compte*.

Comment: Accessoirement, même si ce n'est pas la question, "pas prêt de dormir" n'est pas correct : on dira plutôt "pas prêt _à_ dormir", ou bien "pas _près_ de dormir" (plus familier)

Comment: @Renard Effectivement, je vais apporter une correction dans ce sens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voici quelques expressions que je pourrais utiliser :

*J’imagine que ça ne doit pas*

- *avoir de rapport avec*
- *être en rapport avec*
- *relever de*
- *être lié à*
- *s'agir de*   (ou plutôt: *qu'il ne s'agit pas de*)

*ta situation financière.*

ainsi que deux de celles déjà proposées :

- *avoir un rapport avec*
- *concerner*

Comment: *Concerner*, qui était proposé par l'auteur, me semble une réponse tout a fait appropriée également. *Relever de* me semble assez désuet.

Comment: @ArwynFr Oui, j'avais oublié de reprendre *concerner*, merci !